# Use a reference to a String resource as a name attribute for other resources

Tags: android, xml, string, android-resources

Is it possible to create an resource in XML where the `name` attribute references to a String resource?

Let me show an example:

In my strings.xml I have:

`<string name="some_string">I am a string</string>`

Can I (in some way) use the String resource as a name for another resource? As in:

`<integer name="@string/some_string">1</integer>`

---

To clarify some things:

- I know you can reference the **value** of an resource to a reference:

`<string name="another_string">@string/some_string</string>`

- I already tried doing it without quotes:

`<integer name=@string/some_string>1</integer>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this will ever work.

Also this would be a very bad idea, because the value of your String can change by translations to other languages. Following this the name (ID) of your integer would change by using your App in different countries. This could break your code by changing the Phones default language.

Comment: Now you mention it, that's true. Even when making a single-language app, it would break things at some point. 

Thanks for waking me up, I'll accept it as an answer in 8 min.

Answer (score 1):

As mentiond in the documentation of the [More Resource Types](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)
 :

name : String. A name for the string. This name will be used as the resource ID.

so you cant do this .

hope that helps